# Home and End keys stopped working with Eclipse Kepler on Windows

Tags: eclipse

Can anyone help me understand why my Home and End keys stopped working in Eclipse?  Shift-Home and Shift-End still work as usual.

Restarting Eclipse does not fix the problem.

I double-checked that the key bindings in Preferences are still correct for Line Start and Line End.

Comment: Which eclipse version and OS are you using?Is these not working in editor or views?In which view?In which editor java, c, php etc.

Comment: Kepler Service Release 2 on Windows 7.  Build id: 20140224-0627.
 The home/end keys don't work in the editor, but they work in other views like Console, Project Navigator etc.

Comment: which type of editor is this. C/Java/php etc or not working in all editors in general?

Comment: Not getting any more clues to troubleshoot this problem.1. Change scheme from default to something else and check whether its working and change it back to default and check. 2. Try to refresh preferences by deleting  `.metadata` folder in your workspace and start eclipse.  `Note that all your preferences will be set to default after deleting this folder`

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK thanks for the solution deleting .metadata worked for me

Comment: @AmarMagar Added my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not getting any more clues to troubleshoot this problem. Try this:

1. Change scheme from default to something else and check whether its working and change it back to default and check.
2. Try to refresh preferences by deleting .metadata folder in your workspace and start eclipse.
   **Note that all your preferences will be set to default after deleting this folder**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Kepler version in Linux.

Close eclipse and open it solved my problem with home/end keys.

Comment: I have the same problem, Eclipse Kepler CDT on Linux Slackware 64bit. Home and End keys randomly stop working (when eclipse loses focus). Restarting Eclipse fixes this, but it's really a pain in the but to do so every 5 minutes.

Comment: turns out I was using a very old version of eclipse (2013). I updated to Oxygen and everything's fine now